# Decode a high profile H.264 stream to baseline profile

Tags: android, decode, h.264

I have to show a video stream on my VideoView. But video is High profile H.264 encoded. So it could not run on Android 2.3 devices. I need to decode it to baseline profile on runtime. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Profile is an encoding setting, not a decoding setting. If you have a video in Main profile, and want it in Baseline, you must decode then re-encode (This is call transcode).

The problem is that your device can not decode Main profile in hardware. You can decode in software, but that will likely be slow (possibly slower than real time) and kill the battery. You best bet is it transcode the video first on a PC, or a cloud transcoding service before sending to the device.

Comment: Is there a way to know at runtime if a device is capable of decoding high profile ?